# Repetition record on sql query for 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have this query that return to me all rows for one user

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer , bills , vouchers
WHERE 
bills.bills_CustomerName = customer.customer_Name and
vouchers.vouchers_CustomerName = customer.customer_Name and
bills.bills_CustomerName like '%".$_POST["MyName"]."%'
";
```

I have the problem that one row are repeated 2 times, the `customer` table is related to the `bills` table and to the `vouchers` table on one FK column.

`bills` table :

```
bills_ID  - bills_CustomerName - bills_Total
```

`customer` table :

```
customer_ID - customer_Name - customer_Tell
```

`vouchers` table :

```
vouchers_ID - vouchers_CustomerName - vouchers_Total
```

we are get

```
Name       Total    Tell 

kam johin   100      0444444444
kam johin   100      0444444444
mak pop    200      0588888888
mak pop    200      0588888888
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data. What bills_CustomerName and vouchers_CustomerName contains?

Comment: We still need to see what **data** you have in your tables, and what the output is (so that we can see what data gets duplicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If customer to bill is one-to-many and customer to voucher is also one-to-many then you have what is sometimes known as a "chasm trap", and you will have to aggregate child values from bill and voucher before joining to customer.

Or perhaps your data model should be more like:- Customer->Bill->Voucher, in which case you need to include in the voucher table a foreign key to the Bill to which the voucher relates.

BTW you could probably use some surrogate key for customer - what happens when two different customers have the same name?